# Can you insulate over radiant decking?

Tags: insulation, attic

I’m adding fiberglass batts to my garage attic which already had radiant decking. Is this a bad idea? I bought $1300 worth of R19 batts and stapled about half of one side already. I left a gap down at the bottom for the sofffit vent to still flow some air but wondered if the fiberglass would mess up anything. I know radiant needs an air gap but it wasn’t cutting it as a stand-alone insulation. Thanks.

Comment: Type of attic roof?  Usually insulation is placed on top of the living/use ceiling space, not on the roof decking/rafters.  So garage space, ceiling/top of garage space, vapour barrier, insulation, empty attic space, roof decking, roof.  Pictures of garage will help.

Comment: Is there a ridge vent? Is there air space between the back of the insulation as installed and the presumably shiny underside of the roof decking (never met radiant decking but that must be what you mean? Seems to match up when I search.) If so, should work, if there's room for air to flow from the soffits to ridge vents between the insulation and the shiny roof decking. If not, probably going to cause some problems. Tells us in more detail, show us some pictures, [edit] your post to do those things.